# pandas merge without specifying "on"

Tags: pandas, merge

I want to verify if my understanding on merge function is correct

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'], 'D':['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})

pd.merge(left, right)
```

will be equal to

```
pd.merge(left, right, on= "key")
```

Is this correct?

Comment: According to the documentation this is not true. Without a key, the merge is based on an intersection of all columns:   ---   on : label or list
Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is (in the given example).

In `pd.merge(left, right)` no join columns are given (`on`, `left_on` and `right_on` are all `None`) nor do we join on indices (both `left_index` and `right_index` are `False`). In this case, the join in done on all common columns (the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) call it more technically *'the intersection of the columns'*)

From the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/62a87bf4a2af02a8d3bc271ad26e5994292b8e6a/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py#L1197) we see that `pd.merge(left, right)` internally becomes `pd.merge(left, right, left_on=['key'], right_on=['key'])` which is equivalent to `pd.merge(left, right, on=['key'])` and eventually to `pd.merge(left, right, on='key')`.