# pandas - merge documentation - what are default keys?

Tags: pandas, merge

Trying to understand the behavior of the pandas.merge method. It looks it uses the terminology **key** without defining it.

- [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

> Merge DataFrame or named Series objects with a database-style join.
>
> A named Series object is treated as a DataFrame with a single named column.
>
> **The join is done on columns or indexes**. If joining columns on columns, the DataFrame indexes will be ignored. Otherwise if joining indexes on indexes or indexes on a column or columns, the index will be passed on. When performing a cross merge, no column specifications to merge on are allowed.
>
> If both **key** columns contain rows where the key is a null value, those rows will be matched against each other. This is different from usual SQL join behaviour and can lead to unexpected results.

What is the default key that the merge method use? Where is it documented?

It also says `The join is done on columns or indexes`. How merge decides either join on columns or indexes? Where is it documented?

What are the default behavior of the merge method when `left_on`, `right_on`, `left_index`, `right_index` are not specified? Where is the behavior documented?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas merge without specifying "on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476134/pandas-merge-without-specifying-on)

Answer (score 0):

> DataFrame.merge(right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=False, suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False, validate=None)

you pick your ***keys*** by specifying `on`, or both `left_xxx` and `right_yyy` (left_index + right_index / left_index + right_on / left_on + right_index / left_on + right_on).

If you give it `on='user_id'`, then `'user_id'` is the ***key*** for this merge. pandas will look for a column called `'user_id'` in both of your left and right dataframe, finding matches and do the merge.

You use `merge` like this `df1.merge(df2, ...)`. `df1` is always the left dataframe, and `df2`, which is provided as an argument to the method `merge`, is the right dataframe.

If you provide `left_on='user_id', right_on='customer_id'`, then pandas will look for a column called `'user_id'` from the left dataframe, and a column called `'customer_id'`from the right dataframe, again, finding matches and do the merge.

So you tell pandas which columns to pick from the left and from the right dataframe for the merge action. You specify names with `on`, you are telling pandas that those names exist in both dataframe. Otherwise you use  `left_xxx` and `right_xxx` to ask pandas to look for different names from them.